# Создать новый PDF по шаблону

Tags: c#, файлы, pdf, itextsharp

Вопрос по библиотеке `itextSharp`. У меня есть шаблон pdf документа, который я использую для формирования новых отчетов с данными из программы. Собственно:

```
string templateFile = @"EmptyBlank.pdf";
using (var existingFileStream = new FileStream(templateFile, FileMode.Open))
using (var newFileStream = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)))
    {
         var PdfReader = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);
         newFileStream.NewPage();
         newFileStream.Add(new Paragraph("text",font)); 
         PdfReader.Close();
     }
```

Здесь я пытаюсь создать новый pdf, используя известный шаблон `EmptyBlank` и добавить один новый параграф с "text". Все компилируется, выполняется, но новый файл: 0 байт, и не открывается. 
Такой вариант создает файл с содержимым но не по шаблону:

```
            string templateFile = @"EmptyBlank.pdf";
            using (var existingFileStream = new FileStream(templateFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var pdfReader = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document,  new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    document.Open();
                    document.Add(new Paragraph("123123213",font);      
                }
                document.Close();
                pdfReader.Close();
            }
```

пишет - доступ к закрытому файлу не возможен.
Вопрос, где я ошибся? Спасибо.

Comment: `PdfReader` создаётся, но никак не используется. Также оберните в `using` создание второго `FileStream`.

Comment: PdfReader  не содержит метода Add что бы его использовать. PdfReader .Add(new Paragraph("_" , font)) - это выдает ошибку

Comment: Разумеется, Reader нужен для чтения, откуда у него возьмётся Add? В любом случае вы не используете PdfReader, в этом, очевидно, ошибка (возможно, не единственная). Для чего он вам? Что вы хотели с ним сделать (но забыли)?

Comment: @VladD В принципе достаточно взять фоновое изображение из EmptyBlank.pdf и использовать как фоновое изображение в новом pdf документе. Потом на фон накладывается текст и другие изображения

Comment: @VladD  пробовал взять просто JPG из EmptyBlank.pdf но тогда текст пропадает. хотя картинки наслаиваются как положено (фоновое, на фоновом несколько других согласно SetAbsolutePosition(x,y)) но текст пропадает.